# Facebook Javascript SDK: Can't load a page's public feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a page's public feed with the facebook JS API/Open Graph, but I keep getting an error saying `"An access token is required to request this resource."`. It looks like it's requesting something along the lines of an [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/), but this requires for the user to log into facebook, and I want this to just show a page's public feed without having to login. Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '278343965835848',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.6'
    });

    FB.api('/100006804306358/feed', response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    /*js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";*/
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Checking right now...

Comment: This article was in one of the comments as well, it should help you understand the different kinds of access tokens as well http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: 100006804306358 is not a page it is a user. The user need to grant user_posts permission to the app for you to get their public posts

Comment: I thought I could view user and public pages equally without login?

Comment: On facebook.com yes. Using the API no